# forfiles in certain subfolder in multiple folders

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, subdirectory, delete-file, forfiles

Is there away to only display files in a folder called "Export", when such a subfolder is in multiple locations?

This will display all `.xlsx` files below where I'm running the batch file from, however I don't want to display all, I only want to display things in a folder called "Export":

```
forfiles -p "%~dp0\" -s -m *.xlsx -d -365 -c "cmd /c ECHO @relpath"
```

I have attempted things like:

```
forfiles -p "%~dp0\*\Export" -s -m *.xlsx -d -365 -c "cmd /c ECHO @relpath"
```

However it doesn't recognise syntax like this. Says `invalid argument/option`, but they are valid until I add `*\` to the path.
This is an example of the structure I'm working with and what I what results to display:

> ```
> %~dp0\1\Exports\Excel\                   - (Do display .xlsx files)
> %~dp0\1\Do Not Delete\Excel\             - (Don't display .xlsx files)
> %~dp0\2\Exports\Excel\                   - (Do display .xlsx files)
> %~dp0\2\Do Not Delete\Excel\             - (Don't display .xlsx files)
> ```

The number folders would be a variable somehow, which is why the `*\` is in my attempt.

I will then edit this to delete the files when I know it's picking up the right ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two nested `forfiles` loops:

```
forfiles /S /P "%~dp0\" /M "Export*" /C "cmd /C if @isdir==TRUE forfiles /P @path\Excel /M *.xlsx /D -365 /C 0x22cmd /C echo 00x7840path0x22"
```

This command line walks through the given root directory (`%~dp0`) recursively and iterates through all items matching `Export*` (you might replace this pattern by `Export` or `Exports`, depending on your needs); the hierarchy depth is not checked in order to avoid the need of *three* nested loops. Anyway, if the iterated item is a directory, the sub-directory `Excel` is enumerated and searched for items matching `*.xlsx`.

---

#### Supplement:

The above command line may display many error messages like `ERROR: The specified directory does not exist.` or `ERROR: Files of type "*.xlsx" not found.`, depending on your data; to avoid them, redirect STDERR to the `nul` device:

```
2> nul forfiles /S /P "%~dp0\" /M "Export*" /C "cmd /C if @isdir==TRUE forfiles /P @path\Excel /M *.xlsx /D -365 /C 0x22cmd /C echo 00x7840path0x22"
```

The `forfiles` command returns an empty line to STDOUT, so the above command line will contain many of them; to avoid such too, redirect STDERR *and* STDOUT to the `nul` device and redirect only the wished data to the console `con`:

```
1> nul 2>&1 forfiles /S /P "%~dp0\" /M "Export*" /C "cmd /C if @isdir==TRUE forfiles /P @path\Excel /M *.xlsx /D -365 /C 0x22cmd /C 1> con echo 00x7840path0x22"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send results with `|` to `FINDSTR` like this:

```
FORFILES /P . /S /M *.xlsx /D -365 /C "CMD /C ECHO @path" | ^
    FINDSTR "\\Exports\\" | ^
    FINDSTR /I /C:Delete /V
```

So you search every xlsx files located in a certain path (here is current dir) Every xlsx must contain Exports as folder and show every xlsx that doesn't (`/V` Displays only the non-matching lines) contain "delete" (`/I` mean insensitive)

In a batch file you can replace `/P .` by any variable path `/P "%~dp0"` `/P "%CD%"` or send as argument `/P %1`

Also you can do FOR loop to make any command for every match.

In one line to put in console:

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %A in (`forfiles /p . /s /m *.xlsx /D -365 /C "cmd /c ECHO @path" ^|FINDSTR "\\Exports\\" ^|FINDSTR /I /C:Delete /V`) DO @ECHO FAKE-COMMAND %A
```

In a batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in (
        `forfiles /p . /s /m *.xlsx /D -365 /C "cmd /c ECHO @path" ^|FINDSTR "\\Exports\\" ^|FINDSTR /I /C:Delete /V`
    ) DO (
    SET "myfile=%%~A"
    @ECHO FAKE-COMMAND "!myfile!"
)
ENDLOCAL   
GOTO :EOF
```