# Need a cmd/powershell script to delete files for than 30 days old in nested folders

Tags: powershell

We have 30 processes running which generate error screenshots. So we only keep 30 days worth I've been trying to write a Powershell script to do this. The problem I'm facing is with wildcards in the folder crawl. Say I have the following files:

```
C:\Runs\Process-1\AppFiles\Dummy.txt
C:\Runs\Process-1\AppFiles\Dummy.png
C:\Runs\Process-2\AppFiles\DummyPic.png
C:\Runs\Process-3\AppFiles\Dummy.log
C:\Runs\Process-3\AppFiles\Dummy1.png
```

And I want to get rid of all the png files in those subfolders more than 30 days old.

I tried:

```
    ForFiles /p "C:\Runs\Process*" /s /d -30 /m "*.png"
```

but it doesn't like my folder wildcard. Help anyone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [forfiles in certain subfolder in multipule folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32503342/forfiles-in-certain-subfolder-in-multipule-folders)

Answer (score 1):

In Powershell you may try this:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Runs\Process*\AppFiles\*.png" | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) } | Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using *nested* `forfiles` loops:

- An outer `forfiles` loop for the directories, `Process-*`, and;
- An inner `forfiles` loop for the `*.png` files that you wish to delete.

This way you have the additional flexibility of two loops to play with.

---

Another less elegant method would be to use a [`foreach-object`](http://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html) loop, again containing a nested `ForFiles`, with a list of directories supplied to the `foreach-object`. However, then you have to use a pre-determined list of directories. Obviously, you could also use `foreach-object` for the inner loop as well, but again you would need a pre-determined list of `.png` files, which pretty much defeats the whole object of the exercise.

The nested `forfiles` approach is much better, IMHO.